clang-format in vscode not honoring .clang-format file for C++
My project level settings.json is like following:
    "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "disabled",
    "C_Cpp.formatting": "clangFormat",
    "C_Cpp.clang_format_style": "file",
    "C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "Microsoft",
    "C_Cpp.clang_format_path": "<path to `clang-format` binary>",
    "clangd.path": "<path to `clangd` binary>",
    "clangd.arguments": [
        "-log=verbose", 
        "-pretty", 
        "--background-index", 
        "--background-index-priority=low",
        "--clang-tidy",
        "--enable-config",
    ],

And at project level, I have a .clang-format file with following entries -
Language: Cpp
BasedOnStyle: Microsoft
IndentWidth: 4
AccessModifierOffset: -4
ColumnLimit: 100
Standard: c++20
UseTab: Never


AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: Consecutive
AlignConsecutiveBitFields: Consecutive
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: Consecutive
AlignConsecutiveMacros: Consecutive
AlignEscapedNewlines: LeftWithLastLine
AlignOperands: Align
AlignTrailingComments: Never
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: false
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Always
AllowShortCaseExpressionOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortCompoundRequirementOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Inline
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: WithoutElse
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: Inline
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false

# AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
# AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: true

# BinPackParameters: OnePerLine
BinPackArguments: false
BitFieldColonSpacing: After
BreakAdjacentStringLiterals: true
BreakAfterReturnType: Automatic
BreakBeforeConceptDeclarations: Always
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: false
# BreakBinaryOperations: RespectPrecedence
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeComma
BreakFunctionDefinitionParameters: false
BreakInheritanceList: AfterComma
BreakStringLiterals: false
BreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes

CompactNamespaces: false
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true

EmptyLineAfterAccessModifier: Leave
EmptyLineBeforeAccessModifier: Always

IncludeBlocks: Regroup
IndentCaseBlocks: true
IndentCaseLabels: false
InsertNewlineAtEOF: true
# InsertTrailingCommas: true

MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 2

PointerAlignment: Right

ReferenceAlignment: Right

RemoveEmptyLinesInUnwrappedLines: true
RemoveParentheses: ReturnStatement

SkipMacroDefinitionBody: true
SortIncludes: CaseInsensitive
SortUsingDeclarations: Lexicographic
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: true
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCaseColon: true
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: false
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatementsExceptControlMacros
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true
SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets: false
SpaceInEmptyBlock: false
SpacesInAngles: Always
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true

However, I am getting a strange indentation - in some cases it is creating 2-space indentations and in some cases, it is doing 4-space indentations.
clang-format version 15.0.6
clangd version 19.1.0
There is no other .clang-format file in the project. What could be going wrong? I am using remote server.

The issue is resolved after switching to the latest clang-format coming from CLion distribution.
